# How to check of a Node is inside a form tag?

Tags: xpath

Using XPath, how do I determine if a node is within a form tag?  I guess I am trying to locate the form tag of its ancestor/preceding (but I couldn't get it to work).

example 1:

```
<form id="doNotKnowIDofForm">
<div id="level1">
    <span id="mySpan">someText</span>
</div>
</form>
```

example 2:

```
<form id="doNotKnowIDofForm">
   This is a closed form.
</form>
<div id="level1">
    <span id="mySpan">someText</span>
</div>
</form>
```

I can use xpath `"//span[id='mySpan']"` to locate the span node. But I would like to know if mySpan is inside a form (I do not know the id of the form). I have tried `"//span[id='mySpan']/preceding::form/"` and `"//span[id='mySpan']/ancestor::form/"`

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I would like the XPath to select the myForm form tag in Example1 but ***NOT*** in Example2

Comment: What's wrong with `/ancestor::form`? XML in your second example is not valid, `</form>` is not matched by opening tag.

Comment: In your edit, did you actually mean "myForm" or "mySpan"?

Comment: Technically, an attribute could be described as being "within" a (start) tag, but elements are always between a start tag and an end tag, they are never "within a tag". And you're not trying to locate a form (start or end) tag, you are trying to locate an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your own attempt

```
//span[id='mySpan']/ancestor::form/
```

looks fine to me.

Comment: With a slash at the end, it's invalid XPath.  Without that it should work.

Comment: I just realized that the problem wasn't the XPath but that the original html was malformed, thus making me unable to find the form node (the html is a big long mess).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure from your description whether you're looking to select the `form` element, or the `span` element.  It seems more likely that you're going for the `form`, so I'll address that first.

Your XPath with the `ancestor::form` would have been ok if it didn't have the slash at the end, but it's more roundabout than it needs to be.  I think this is a better way:

```
//form[.//span/@id = 'mySpan']
```

or this:

```
//form[descendant::span/@id = 'mySpan']
```

To produce an XPath that locates certain nodes only if they are within a form, you would put the `ancestor::form` inside the predicate:

```
//span[@id = 'mySpan' and ancestor::form]
```

or you can do this, which would again be more straightforward:

```
//form//span[@id = 'mySpan']
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your attempt!  It's really nice. But unfortunately I am actually looking for the form element and not the mySpan element. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: @JosephLee Because your question was unclear I provided you two versions of **both answers**. As I said: **It seems more likely that you're going for the `form`, so I'll address that first.** Either of the first two XPaths in my answer should work for finding the `form` element, and they are both more logical than your approach of first locating the `span` and then climbing back up to the form with `ancestor::form`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use,

"form//span[id='mySpan']"

Comment: This doesn't select `form`, which is what OP wants.